# Create NSManagedObject in one view and save in another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I want to know what the best way to implement a certain functionality. I have a message composer view where the user creates a `NSManagedObject MessageObject`. I also have a class `ObjectHelper` which has a global instance initialized.

I have a background (private queue) `NSManagedObjectContext` create a `MessageObject` immediately when the user enters the compose view. The catch here is that the `ObjectHelper` (**not** the ComposerViewController) is the owner of this new object - it has a property variable with a strong reference:

`ObjectHelper.h:`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MessageObject *newObject;
```

Then, back in my `ComposeViewController`, I set a timer to save the object to disk every 30 seconds (this saves a draft, like auto-save, in case the user gets interrupted somehow or the application crashes, the data doesn't get wiped out).

Then, when the user hits the save button, I want to make sure I do as little work as possible on the main thread so that the dismiss modal view animation is smooth, and function returns to the main view controller quickly. So what I do is create an `NSDictionary` with all the values of the message object, call `[globalObjectHelperInstance updateNewObjectInstanceWithDictionary:]`

What this does is update the `newObject` instance that was already created in the beginning of the compose view with the values from the dictionary, and does it in the background thread.

Then I dismiss the modal.

I have a few questions here (please answer whatever you can):

1. Is there a better way to implement "draft" saving functionality rather than creating a property instance in the `ObjectHelper`? (the reason I create a property instance in an outside class other than the `ComposeController` is because the view controller dismisses while background work is being done on the object, so I'm afraid it will disappear from memory if I make it an instance variable.)
2. Should the property reference be a weak or strong? I know an `NSManagedObjectContext` is not guaranteed to retain its objects, unless (I think) these objects have pending, unsaved changes.
3. For some reason, calling `[backgroundMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:self.newObject error:&error]`in the `[globalObjectHelperInstance updateNewObjectInstanceWithDictionary:]` before saving causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. I'm guessing this has something to do with the way I'm managing memory in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your way to save draft seems very fine to me.

   Another option is not to keep the property reference in any object and fetch the draft object by some key, update it and save it again. This might make sense in case you save something rarely or have something very big, but your current approach seems much more suited.
2. The reference should be strong. You want it to be present at all times while you want to update it, and you require its existence, so that qualifies for strong. In case of weak reference the object might get deleted. The object in the database on disk will remain, but your in-memory representation will be removed, you wouldn't want that—to update a nil reference.

   I don't see any reason why this might cause any memory overuse or leaks, it's just one object and this isn't a case to be afraid of circular references.
3. As for your crash, it is hard for me to tell, but maybe you should obtain ID in the main thread's MOC at first, and then use it in the background MOC? Also, since it is easier to transfer `NSDictionary` between thread boundaries rather than an `NSManagedObject`, maybe you should keep your draft in the background MOC all the time?

   Your code in the `updateNewObjectInstanceWithDictionary:` would then call a GCD block on the background queue and pass it the dictionary to save.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For point 3, wouldn't I need to first save in the background context, which is a child of the main context, before obtaining child ids? Because the main context would still not know about this new object if I don't save to the background one first, right? And as for keeping my object in the background MOC at all times, isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: If you create or fetch this draft object from the background MOC, then yes, that's what you're doing :). Then my response isn't relevant on that point, and I don't think I know enough to comment further on your crash. I always avoid moving data through thread boundaries, keeping small objects on the main thread and leaving only sync in background.

Comment: As for the crash, if I replace `[backgroundMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:self.newObject error:&error]` with `[backgroundMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:backgroundMOC.managedObjects.allObjects error:&error]`, the crash goes away. Any ideas what this could mean?

Comment: Oh, it seems you're passing an object instead of the array. Try passing [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.newObject].

Comment: Ha, I think that might have just been a typo..I typed that line manually here rather than copy paste, but in my code I do pass in an array